# Excel & WPF modal form

Tags: wpf, office-interop

I've got this situation. (.net 3.5)

A Winform application that with OleAutomation and Office Interop create an excel, a toolbar and handlers for buttons in the toolbar.

Now we've got some functionality that shows the user modal windows (winform 2.0) with the method:

```
form.ShowDialog(new ExcelHwndWrapper(objExcelApplication.HWND))
```

And the "owner" of the modal form is set to the "excel" window.

Now I would like to create some WPF Window instead of Winforms due to layout requirements for new functionalities.

Is there any way to Show a WPF ModalDialog "over" excel Window ?

I found something for showing a WPF ModalDialog "over" a winform, but nothing over excel.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the excel Window still a WPF Window with interop content inside? Seems like you should be able to simply call Window.ShowDialog(), right?

Answer (score 2):

When using VSTO and Office 2007, I've had trouble using WPF Windows as modal dialogues.  What I found that worked much better was creating a Winforms Form and putting an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control inside it, then putting my WPF content inside that.

When I used WPF Windows without the Winforms wrapper I ran into trouble with properly capturing keyboard input, among other things.

As long as you make the ElementHost stretch to fill the entire dialogue it'll look like you have a WPF Window.